# Delete a Dataset in Powershell for Power BI

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am trying to delete a Dataset in a workspace from Powershell using Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod.

I am usin below syntax:
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'url' -Method Delete.

But when I try to run this I am getting "one or more error occurred" as the error message. Am I using this method correctly?

Comment: Is that the syntax you're using verbatim? If so, you need to include the relative URL to the dataset you want to delete.

Comment: Not verbatim - this is sample syntax. I am adding the whole url which include group ID & dataset id

Comment: hmmm.... any more info on the exact errors then? Also; I'm assuming you only included the whole url relative to your PowerBI workspace (so removed the 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg' part)

Comment: The exact error is "Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod : One or More errors occurred". Yes I am only using the url relative to my workspace. Just to add I am trying the delete a Dataset which is not in my workspace however I am using an admin profile.